# Java -- Checking for equality based on a subset of the data of two objects

Tags: java, comparison, equals

The problem I am trying to solve is trying to remove data from one list that "matches" data in another list, where I define matching as being equal in two attributes that I have defined.

Let's say the object is a Box. It has a String size, a Color color, and a String owner.

I say that two boxes are equal if they have the same size and same color. Note that I can't redefine the Box object but I suppose I could subclass it if needed.

If my definition of equal was same size, then I'd do this in O(N) with a set.

```
Set<String> boxSizes = newHashSet();
for (Box box : boxList1) {
  boxSizes.add(box.getSize());
} 

for (Box box : boxList2) {
  if (boxSizes.contains(box.getSize()) {
     // This is a duplicate
  }
}
```

I could emulate this same solution for checking for equality based on both size and color by writing a small class and implementing equals in that way. however, this solution seems overblown for such a simple comparison.

I could also construct the key out of some combination of the attributes I care about, e.g.

```
  boxKeys.add(box.getSize() + box.color.toString());
```

This would likely work, although there are certainly a few edge cases. I don't have any strong argument against this solution other than it just feels wrong.

So, what kind of solution should be implemented for this operation?

Answer (score 0):

A `TreeSet` breaks the `Set` contract by using `compareTo()` instead of `equals()` to determine object equality. You could use a custom `Comparator` to achieve what you want. Only need to write a single additional class (and make the `compareTo()` sensible for non-equal objects too).